# JqueryUI DatePicker - Calculate date difference resulting NaN

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, nan

I'm new to jquery. so I dont know too much about jquery. I want to calculate how much the days from datepicker. I tried tips from here but the result is always NaN. I tried parse, int parse, date parse and the result is still NaN. Please help me to Fix this code.

[I'm using Keith Wood Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) The basis is from jqueryUI

And here is my code :

```js
$(function() {
    $('#from,#to').datepick({
     //dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: '+1y',
  changeMonth: true,
  onSelect: (customRange, total),
    });
 
});

function customRange(dates) {
 if (this.id == 'from') {
  $('#to').datepick('option', 'minDate', dates[0] || null);
  $( "#listRender" ).datepick( "option", "minDate", dates[0] || null);
 }
 else {
  $('#from').datepick('option', 'maxDate', dates[0] || null);
  $( "#listRender" ).datepick( "option", "maxDate", dates[0] || null);
 }
}

function total() {
 var start = $('#from').datepick('getDate');
 var end = $('#to').datepick('getDate');
 var total = (end-start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
 $('#total_days').val(total);
    //alert(total);
 
}
```

```html
<p>
  Arrive Date : <input type="text" name="arriveDate" placeholder="Arrival" id="from" readonly="true"/>
</p>

<p>
Departure Date : <input type="text" name="departDate" placeholder="Departure" id="to" readonly="true"/>
</p>

<p>
Total Days : <input type="text" id="total_days" placeholder="Total Day" id="total_days" readonly="true"/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the total calculation only if both the values are present

```
function total() {
    //looks like getDate is returning an array
    var start = $('#from').datepick('getDate')[0];
    var end = $('#to').datepick('getDate')[0];
    var total = start && end ? (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 : '';
    $('#total_days').val(total);
    //alert(total);

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y4t9a7r4/)

Comment: Hello sir, Thank you for answering my question. The textbox is not showing the result of the total days. I think there is an error in my datepicker.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry for the late post. Thanks for fix my code, its work, the code work with a little change from me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function total() {
    var start = new Date($('#from').val())||0;
    var end = new Date($('#to').val())||0;

    if(start > 0 && end > 0)
    {
    var total = (end-start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    $('#total_days').val(total);
    //alert(total);
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4s8s5zt9/6/)**

Comment: Hello thank you for answering my question. The result is 0, where do you think the error?

Comment: put alert for start and end datepicker values and check what it is returning. like `alert($('#from').datepick('getDate'))`. Share jsfiddle link with your problem, so that i can help you better.

Comment: Hello, here is my fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/denyseti/4s8s5zt9/

The result from alert is :
Thu Nov 20 2014 12:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)